# 2d OpenGL Rotation around center of Object

Tags: opengl, rotation

My code doesnt work correctly.

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    // Here I translate the camera so that the point 0/0 will be at the 
    //bottom left of the screen
    gl.glTranslatef(CameraX, CameraY, CameraZ);
    // then I draw the object to rotate like many threads here said:
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    // translate to the middlepoint of object
    gl.glTranslatef(object.getPosX() + object.getWidth()/2, object.getPosY()               + object.getHeight()/2, 0);
    // rotate
    gl.glRotatef(30, 0, 0, 1);              
    object.draw(gl);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
```

The problem is that it doesnt do a rotation around the center. It only translates the coordinates of the object, to the given point and then rotates around the coordinates. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in OpenGL, glRotate doesn't specify an orientation, as e.g. in Blender, but a rotation around the origin. What you need to do is:

```
translate(-pivot); // Make the pivot the origin
rotate(); // rotate around origin
translate(pivot); // translate back
```

Comment: @user3337420 Nice. :) Please mark it as the accepted answer so others know the question is answered.